# trigger onclick event on HTML select-options if only one option field is available

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i have one html select dropdown with 5 options (list of car manufacturers), here user clicks on one option and `onchangeHandler` will get the selected value. depending on this selected value, another dropdown will be shown to the user (list of car models). and it works fine.

However if i have just one option in the list for car manufacturer, i need to show it as pre-selected(which i am able to) in `carManufacturer` dropdown and also automatically show its respective `carModels` dropdown, which i am not able to.

below is the code which opens up `carModels` dropdown on selecting a particular `carManufacturer`

```
public carMfgSelected(event: any) {
   const carMfg = event.nativeEvent.target.value;
   this.setState({carMfgselected: carMfg});
}
     render(){
      <div>
        <span>Select car manufacturer : </span>
        <select id="carMfgSelection" onChange={this.carMfgSelected} value={this.carMfgList.length === 1 ? this.carMfgList[0].mfgName : ''}>
          <option value="">select</option>
          {...looping through carMfgList}
        </select>
      </div>
       {this.state.carMfgselected ?
        <div>
        <span>Select car model : </span>
        <select id="carModelSelection" onChange={this.carModelSelected}>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
          <option value="merc">Merc</option>
          <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
        </select>
      </div> : <></>}
     }
```

My question is, how do i trigger `event.nativeEvent.target.value` in the click handler when i have to show my first drowdown as preselected incase i  only have one option in my `carMfgList` array?

Answer (score 0):

Hope your options are not hardcoded like this.

You need to check the length of the options coming in and then call the handler.

```
render(){

this.props.carModelOptions.length == 1 ? this.carMfgSelected(this.props.carModelOptions[0]) : null;

return {...}
}
```